# change navigation drawer when call fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have created a navigation drawer using fragments. I have a function that changes fragments when clicked on drawerlist item. I have Some created some fragments. I want to call another fragment inside current fragment on a button click. but when I click on Button It actually changes fragment but I want navigation to be changed as well when fragment is called. Please suggest me something.

I have two fragments named HomeFragment and FindPeopleFragment. and a button in HomeFragment fragment that calls FindPeopleFragment

Here is my button click event written in HomeFragment

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.find_people);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is code that changes fragments in MainActivity

```
Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
```

Here is code written in onCreate of MainActivity

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is link of code  in which I am doing same thing [link](https://github.com/rohit-iiita/SlidingMenu/)

Comment: What do you mean by change navigation drawer? Do you want another navigation drawer on fragment change? If so, it might not be possible. You can have different navigation drawers for different activities but not for different fragments of same activity.

Comment: @Apurva When I select FindPeopleFragment from drawerlist it shows me selected. but when I call it from HomeFragment then drawerlist still shows me HomeFragment as selected. I want that to be updated when I call FindPeople fragment from HomeFragment.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar issue. I wanted Next Fragment to be loaded on event. i.e On main fragment's on button click, next fragment should be loaded. And the when Navigation drawer is opened, selected item should be one which is loaded.

I have solved issue by calling the method, **setItemChecked** on Navigation Drawer list object.

```
if (mDrawerListView != null) {
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to do but it worked for me.